# Членимая ли основа?

Tags: морфемика

Являются ли глаголы в данных значениях членимыми? Если да, то почему?
-завести машину
-завести попугая

Comment: Вопрос неясен. В каком смысле "членимые глаголы"?

Comment: морфемный разбор слова

Comment: @ТатьянаАлексеевна А что сложного? За- — приставка, -вес- — корень, -ти — окончание или суффикс.

Comment: @Максим "завести попугая" - это не вести попугая, а приобрести.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильно:

***за/вес/ти** попугая;*

***за/вес/ти** машину.*

Пояснение

1. У Тихонова  глагол ***завести*** образован от глагола ***вести***, причем **во всех значениях.**
2. Но ведь значения такие разные, как такое возможно?  Это лексико-семантический способ словообразования.

**[Лексико-семантический способ словообразования](https://russkiiyazyk.ru/slovoobrazovanie/sposoby-slovoobrazovaniia.html)**  представляет собой **распад значений многозначного слова**. Значения слова расходятся по смыслу настолько далеко друг от друга, что образуют отдельные **лексические единицы**. Так в русском языке возникают омонимы:   титан — гигант, вступивший в схватку с врагом; титан — большой металлический бак для кипячения воды; титан — твердый металл.

Многозначным является глагол ***вести***, а также глагол ***заводить*** (завести).

3. Глагол ***завести*** образуется от глагола ***вести*** с помощью приставки ***ЗА,*** которая обозначает **совершенный вид** глагола, а также придает ему различные **семантические** оттенки (приставка ***ЗА*** тоже многозначная).  Поэтому приставка ***ЗА*** выделяется при разборе.
4. **[У Ефремовой](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/163439/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C)**

Заводить: (1) Обзаводиться кем-либо или чем-либо. (2) Приводить в действие механизм, мотор и т.п.

5. **Как увидеть значение «вести»**  в таких разных сочетаниях?

(1) **Начальное** (основное) значение:  ***вести/водить***  —  идя рядом с кем-либо, сопровождая кого-либо, направлять его движение, помогать или заставлять идти.  ***Завести*** —  завершенность действия.

Если **завести попугая**,  то это не просто приобрести его,  но  сопровождать/направлять (вести) **его жизнь** в дальнейшем.

***Завести машину*** — это привести в действие мотор, который будет обеспечивать движение машины,  то есть будет ее  «вести», заставлять ехать.

Answer (score 0):

За/вес/ти - корень вес, при чередовании может давать вес-вод-веш-вож-вё.

Вес - глагольный корень означает вести вола на верёвке-поводке, то есть - тянуть, управлять, владеть. Завести машину, скорее всего вытекает из завести мотор-двигатель, потому что её заводили - приводили в движение - специальным приспособлением, кроме того мотор имеет обычно приводной ремешок - деталь передающую тягу с двигателя на другие движущие детали. Завести попугая, скорее всего связано с обычным употреблением глагола вести по отношению к домашнему животному, то есть иметь попугая в качестве домашнего животного, тоже как вола на верёвочке.